# CSS doesn't always work properly on a mobile device

Tags: css, blazor-server-side, mobile-browser

I created a web application in blazor server, it will be mainly used on mobile devices. I have a problem with the performance of a specific CSS related to displaying the "Bitte warten" animation, when I test it on PC, CSS works fine and looks like this:
[Correct Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhZRO.png)
But on mobile device it some times look like this:
[Not Correct Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWAoD.jpg) (I took a photo of it because device doesn't allow screenshot)

The browser I use to launch the application on a mobile device is Velocity Browser, the device use android 10.

I use chrome browser to launch the application on mobile device and it solved the problem, but I have to stay with Velocity browser.
I would be grateful if someone can tell me what could be causing this problem and how to solve it, or if someone could give me advice how to create something similar but using different approach.

Here is the CSS code I am using to display it:

```css
.location{
    text-align:center;
}

.loader {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    border: 5px solid #0093DD;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    animation: pulse 1s linear infinite;
}

.loader:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    border: 5px solid #0093DD;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    animation: scaleUp 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes scaleUp {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0)
    }

    60%, 100% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1)
    }
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0%, 60%, 100% {
        transform: scale(1)
    }

    80% {
        transform: scale(1.2)
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="location">
    <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the ongoing question web developers ask: should I use VERY basic HTML and CSS in order to maximize coverage, or should I develop for the top 95% of users, possibly with a warning in the page that the Chrome browser is recommended.

I run a paid subscription website, and I chose the latter.  If the newer hardware and browsers use a feature, then I will use the feature.

Comment: I tried to find documentation which might describe what CSS is and isn't supported, but couldn't find anything recent. I guess you'll just have to plod through that before pseudo element, removing and restoring properties one by one and seeing what is not working. Alternatively, go really basic and put another circle in with a 'real' element in the DOM.